# Octave error in sload method after 16.04 update

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, octave

this code was working fine in ocatave untill update ubuntu from  14.04 to 16.04, it gives me this error

> > [Signal, Header] = sload('../data/A01T.gdf');
> >
> > ** On entry to DGEMV  parameter number  3 had an illegal value
> >
> > SLOAD: mexSLOAD('../data/A01T.gdf') failed - the slower M-function is used.
> >
> > error: getfiletype: exception encountered in Fortran subroutine dgemv_
> >
> > error: called from
> >         getfiletype at line 122 column 7
> >         sload at line 668 column 4

Comment: Did you do a clean install of 16.04 or an upgrade?

Comment: update from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS

Comment: So, not a clean install. Mmm, it seems [from here](https://launchpad.net/~octave/+archive/ubuntu/stable) that both Trusty and Xenial are using the same version. For the lack of alternatives, you could purge octave, and install again, or do that for the sload and biosig packages you have.

Comment: i purge octave and seems multiple versions are exist so i purge till gives 

$ sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove octave
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'octave' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

but octave is still exist and still working even after purge

Comment: Ok, then somehow you installed manually. Save everything you want from octave (configs, scripts, etc), and then delete manually. Can you find the location of octave? Maybe `usr/local/`? Or in your home folder? Use Catfish File search to look for every octave file. There must be a hidden config file in your home folder too. Probably `.octave/`. Enable hidden files with Ctrl+H. Once you eliminate everything, reinstall. Let's see how it goes from there.

Comment: "then delete manually" is that means move octave folder to Trash?

Comment: yes. Everything. So then you install from clean using `sudo apt-get`, and see how it performs.